# How to use a function in select along with all the records in Sequalize?

Tags: sql, sequelize.js

Here is a Sequalize query below which retrieves a transformed value based on the table column value.

```
courses.findAll({
  attributes: [ [sequelize.fn('to_char', sequelize.col('session_date'), 'Day'), 'days']]
});
```

The above sequlaize query will return result equal to as followed SQL query.

```sql
select to_char(bs.session_date, 'Day') as days from courses bs;
```

**Expected output:**
I want the transformed value which is in attributes along with all records like below. I know we can mention all the column names in attributes array but it is a tedious job. Any shortcut similar to asterisk in SQL query.

```sql
select to_char(bs.session_date, 'Day') as days,* from courses bs;
```

I tried the below sequalize query but no luck.

```
courses.findAll({
  attributes: [ [sequelize.fn('to_char', sequelize.col('session_date'), 'Day'), 'days'],'*']
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `attributes` option can be passed an object as well as an array of fields for finer tuning in situations like this. It's briefly addressed in [the documentation](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-querying-basics.html#specifying-attributes-for-select-queries).

```js
courses.findAll({
    attributes: {
        include: [
            [ sequelize.fn('to_char', sequelize.col('session_date'), 'Day'), 'days' ]
        ]
    }
});
```

By using `include` we're adding fields to the `courses.*` selection. Likewise we can also include an `exclude` parameter in the `attributes` object which will remove fields from the `courses.*` selection.

Answer (score 2):

There is one shortcut to achieve the asterisk kind of selection in Sequalize. Which can be done as follows...

```
// To get all the column names in an array
let attributes = Object.keys(yourModel.rawAttributes);
courses.findAll({
  attributes: [...attributes ,
[sequelize.fn('to_char', sequelize.col('session_date'), 'Day'), 'days']]
});
```

This is a work around there may be a different option.

Comment: Thanks even this worked but the official way is Include according to the doc.